# How to make this lambda work correctly in Python3?

Tags: python, lambda, syntax-error, python-3.6

Why does this code:

```
import math

def nearest_location(locations, my_location):
    return min(enumerate(locations), key=lambda (_, (x, y)): math.hypot(x - my_location[0], y - my_location[1]))

locations = [(41.56569, 60.60677), (41.561865, 60.602895), (41.566474, 60.605544), (41.55561, 60.63101), (41.564171, 60.604020)]
my_location = (41.565550, 60.607537)

print(nearest_location(locations, my_location))
```

throw errors like:

> Tuple parameter unpacking is not supported in python 3

and

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

When i run it on Python 3.6?

I tried to fix it myself, but I still do not get it... Can somebody help to fix it?

Comment: okay it seems like you don't think it's a duplicate and you can't solve it using the duplicate, so I reopened the question. I was already posting an answer (submitting it now) when I found the other Q+A and I thought it would be an appropriate duplicate (but nobody is perfect, right?). Sorry for the inconvenience and I'll remove my comments in a few minutes. :)

Comment: You can mark this as a duplicate or delete, the main thing you helped me. For that I'm grateful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't unpack the arguments for `lambda` in python-3.x. While they can still accept multiple arguments (i.e. `lambda x, y: x+y`) you can't unpack one argument anymore (i.e. `lambda (x, y): x+y`).

The simplest solution would be to just index the "one argument" instead of using unpacking:

```
import math

def nearest_location(locations, my_location):
    return min(enumerate(locations), key=lambda x: math.hypot(x[1][0] - my_location[0], x[1][1] - my_location[1]))

locations = [(41.56569, 60.60677), (41.561865, 60.602895), (41.566474, 60.605544), (41.55561, 60.63101), (41.564171, 60.604020)]
my_location = (41.565550, 60.607537)

print(nearest_location(locations, my_location))
# (0, (41.56569, 60.60677))
```